# AnnotationProcessorFactory class not found in java 8

Tags: java, web-services, wsdl

I had a project which is build on **java 1.6** and

Now i upgraded the java verion to **1.8 and**  build the project

Here i have used gradle for building the project
Here is the gradle code

```
task wsgen(dependsOn: compileJava)  {

    doLast{
        ant {
            taskdef(name:'wsgen',
                classname:'com.sun.tools.ws.ant.WsGen',
                classpath:configurations.jaxws.asPath)
            wsgen(keep:true,
                destdir: "${buildDir}",
                resourcedestdir:"${sourceSets.main.output.resourcesDir}",
                sourcedestdir:'src/main/java',
                genwsdl:'true',
                classpath:"${configurations.compile.asPath}:${sourceSets.main.output.classesDir}",
                sei:'<sei implementation class>')
        }
    }
}
```

and the error , am getting is

**java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/mirror/apt/AnnotationProcessorFactory**

Can any one tell me, where the issue is located and raising from?

Thank you!!!

Comment: This is the deprecated Java 5 apt tool which was [deprecated in Java 7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/apt/) and [removed in Java 8](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/117).

Comment: Whats the latest jar file name with the version , which can support the java 8 web service generation.

Answer (score -2):

Thanks go out to @McDowell for the useful comment with links. So the APT tool is gone. Use a version 7 JDK for building your project. Just install it alongside your java 8 JDK and create a script specifically for building your project that requires the APT tool.

I had the same problem and went around it by running maven using the 1.7 version of JDK. So I created a script (.cmd on windows platform) that, for me, looks like this:

```
set JAVA_HOME="c:\Java\ibm-jdk-1.7.0"
set PATH=%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%PATH%
mvn clean install eclipse:eclipse
```

This will successfully build using an IBM version of the java 7 jdk, which i happen to have in my java folder. I hate the fact that I can't build my projects with the version 1.8 jdk but at least i can use java 8 features on other projects.