# netbeans 9: error generating WSDL (NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/mirror/apt/AnnotationProcessorFactory)

Tags: java, netbeans, jax-ws, netbeans-9

I'm trying to generate a webservices wsdl using netbeans, but it fail searching AnnotationProcessorFactory, that does not exist in java8 (as I've read googling)
I've tried a new web project from scratch, adding a web services using netbeans wizard.
This create a new class with a hello method

```
@WebService(serviceName = "NewWebService")
public class NewWebService
{

  /**
   * This is a sample web service operation
   */
  @WebMethod(operationName = "hello")
  public String hello(@WebParam(name = "name") String txt)
  {
    return "Hello " + txt + " !";
  }
}
```

after I've lunched the wsdl generation (right click on webservice name and choose "Generate WSDL and copy", it  start to compile and fail on wsgen

```
command line: wsgen -classpath /usr/lib64/java/lib/tools.jar:/home/rcazzola/NetBeansProjects/sugar/WebApplication1/build/web/WEB-INF/classes:/opt/glassfish-4.1.1/glassfish/modules/webservices-osgi.jar:/opt/glassfish-4.1.1/glassfish/modules/endorsed/webservices-api-osgi.jar:/opt/glassfish-4.1.1/glassfish/modules/jaxb-osgi.jar:/opt/glassfish-4.1.1/glassfish/modules/endorsed/jaxb-api.jar -d /home/rcazzola/NetBeansProjects/sugar/WebApplication1/build/generated-sources/jax-ws -Xendorsed -keep -wsdl -r /home/rcazzola/NetBeansProjects/sugar/WebApplication1/build/generated-sources/jax-ws/resources -s /home/rcazzola/NetBeansProjects/sugar/WebApplication1/build/generated-sources/jax-ws -verbose ws.NewWebService
/home/xxxx/NetBeansProjects/sugar/WebApplication1/nbproject/jaxws-build.xml:26: 
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/mirror/apt/AnnotationProcessorFactory
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:642)
 at com.sun.istack.tools.ParallelWorldClassLoader.findClass(ParallelWorldClassLoader.java:90)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
 at com.sun.tools.ws.ant.WsGen2.execute(WsGen2.java:524)
 at com.sun.istack.tools.ProtectedTask.execute(ProtectedTask.java:55)
 at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
 at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor93.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
 at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:99)
 at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:350)
 at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:449)
 at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:470)
 at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1388)
 at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1361)
 at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
 at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1251)
 at org.apache.tools.ant.module.bridge.impl.BridgeImpl.run(BridgeImpl.java:261)
 at org.apache.tools.ant.module.run.TargetExecutor.run(TargetExecutor.java:574)
 at org.netbeans.core.execution.RunClassThread.run(RunClassThread.java:128)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.mirror.apt.AnnotationProcessorFactory
 at com.sun.istack.tools.ParallelWorldClassLoader.findClass(ParallelWorldClassLoader.java:71)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 23 more
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)
```

What I have missed?

Comment: this is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24242856/annotationprocessorfactory-class-not-found-in-java-8

Comment: @Rohit Yadav : it is not: what you have posted is a generic problem, I have also mentioned, but it not help how to fix in netbeans. Where should I insert the "specific script" to generate correctly the wsdl? I've already tried to compile the project against JAVA7 with no result

Comment: @Rohit Yadav : probably you could be helpful if you appoint me on define where upgrade jar with which version to permit the automatic ANT script to finish sucesfully